# How can I find the sup, inf, min, and max of $\bigcup\left[\frac{1}{n}, 2-\frac{1}{n}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

$$\bigcup\left[\frac{1}{n}, 2-\frac{1}{n}\right]$$

I'm not sure how to get started with this one.  When I graph the two functions I see they intersect at the point $(1,1)$, which I take to be the union of the set.

But how do I use this information to obtain the inf, min, sup, and max, particularly if there is only one element in the set?  Is $1$ the inf, min, sup and max?

Comment: @Arthur thank for your comment.  This is the first problem I've had like this involving the sup, inf, min and max so I just tried what seemed logical to me.  help?

Comment: Written out, the set you are working with is $[1,1]\cup[\frac12,2-\frac12]\cup[\frac13,2-\frac13]\cup\cdots$. It's a union of closed intervals. The $n$th interval is wider than (and contains) the one before.  If you unite these, what do you get?

Comment: $\cup\left[\frac{1}{n}, 2-\frac{1}{n}\right]=(0,2)$ it follows inf=$0$;sup=$2$. neither max nor min exist

Comment: The union isn't the intersection, what they have in common.  It's what they have altogether.  [1/2,1 1/2] are in the union so is [1/3, 1 2/3], so is [1/365, 1 364/365] etc.

Comment: Hint: not all four of them actually exist.  In fact two of them do not.

Comment: Here's some more hints.  I can't find any negative numbers in any of the sets.  For any number 0 <x <1 can I find an n so that 1/n <= x <= 2 - 1/n?  So.  min, what is the smallest number I can find that is in a [1/n,2-1/n].  Max, what is the largest number I can find.  Inf, what number is as small as any of the numbers.  Sup, what number is as large as any of the numbers.  Hint: not all those qustion have answers.

Comment: Another hint:  what *is* the union.  Hint......1/4 < 1/3 < 1/2 < 1 < 3/2 < 5/3 < 7/4 ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union consists of all real numbers $x$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$ for some natural number $n$. This is a much larger set than just the single point $\{1\}$. For instance, taking $n=2$ shows that all real numbers $x$ with $\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{3}{2}$ are included in the union.

Some leading questions to get you started: what happens to $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$, and what does this tell you about the union?

Comment: $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ goes to $0$

Comment: Right. So is it possible for any $x>0$ to be less than $\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$?

Comment: No.  So that means the inf: 0 and the minimum would be 0?

Comment: You're right that the infimum is $0$. But $0$ is not contained in any of the sets $[\frac{1}{n},2-\frac{1}{n}]$.

Comment: Is x = 0.00486468 in any of the sets [1/n,2-1/n]?  Is -0.0698432?  Is 0?  Is there a smallest number that is in any of the sets?  Is there a limit to the smallest numbers that are in the sets?